# Getting an odd java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: java, apache, jsp, exception

I'm getting an odd exception when running my java web project. It seems like this 'randomly' happened after I saved some changes to one of my JSPs. I don't ever remember changing around any settings. I've never run into any errors like this before from this project, it's had no problem finding the `HubPortal` class before.

Here's the full stack trace:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /hubmainpage.jsp at line 7

4: %>
5: <%
6: String responsepage = request.getParameter("show");
7: HubPortal hp = new HubPortal();
8: List processList = hp.getProcessList();
9: List clientList = hp.getClientList();
10: List transList = hp.getTransactionTypeList();


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
    org.apache.jsp.hubmainpage_jsp._jspService(hubmainpage_jsp.java:783)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    com.middleware.hts.HubPortal.<clinit>(HubPortal.java:23)
    org.apache.jsp.hubmainpage_jsp._jspService(hubmainpage_jsp.java:66)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Any ideas as to why I'm all of a sudden encountering this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> 7: HubPortal hp = new HubPortal();
>
> root cause 
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
>     com.middleware.hts.HubPortal.<clinit>(HubPortal.java:23)
> ```

This means that the [log4j jar file](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html) is missing in webapp's runtime classpath while it is been required by the `HubPortal` class. You need to put it in the same place as the JAR file containing the `HubPortal` class, for example the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder or wherever else the `HubPortal` class is.

Comment: I put the jar with the src (which has the HubPortal class in it) and it fixed the error I was encountering, however, it did produce another one. (I would put it here, but I went over the character limit!)

http://pastebin.com/s5Ldg7hz

Comment: Apparently there are other dependencies, but the exception doesn't contain helpful information now. Putting Java code in normal Java classes instead of JSP files should result in more clear exceptions. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202

Comment: Okay, thanks. But, any idea as to why this error appeared out of the blue?

Comment: Either the classpath has been messed up (or, contrarily, has been cleaned up and thus exposed hidden problems), or some circumstance changed which caused HubPortal to indirectly instantiate Log4j while it did not do that by default, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to everyones answer I want to say some
tips For java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError or java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

1. You should first confirm your classpath
2. You need to ensure the required classes under
   `%CONTEXT-ROOT%/WEB-INF/Classes(Servlet directory)` or
   If the dependent classes availble to you as JAR then it  is inside `%CONTEXT-ROOT%/WEB-INF/lib/xyz.jar`. Remember the container needs to access these classes during runtime!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your HubPortal class is not able to find the Logger class, make that available as part of your web-inf.

Comment: I just checked, and I have the .jar for the Logger class in my WEB-INF

Comment: try using a tool like agent ransack to identify if that class is actually in that jar and try restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not deploying the log4j jar. This should be part of your war, in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: I currently have the commons-logging jar in my WEB-INF

Comment: @Balusc oops, you're right, just saw the org.apache. Changed now.